# Why is PhoneGap Build showing an error?

Tags: cordova

I am developing a project in PhoneGap with Eclipse. It is working working fine in Android, but the in PhoneGap Build the .ipa file shows an error. How can I give the bundle identifier for iOS in PhoneGap with Eclipse IDE and next key unlocking process?

Answer (score 4):

error - your ios signing key is locked. you can fix this
[image]

Insert your IOS certificate password after click submit key button.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you cant add this with eclipse. if youre using phonegapbuild then you can read some info [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/signing_signing-ios.md.html#iOS%20Signing) if not, you have to do this on Mac with xCode IDE (either way, you will need Mac)

Comment: Thanks Marchin, pls let me know 'i am already taken the .p12&provision files from other ios developers'.I am using These files in pg builder , finally i get "Error - Your IOS signing key is locked. - You can fix this" error.pls  help me.........?

Comment: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/ios_signing_key_is_locked_but_correct_password_was_given

Comment: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/build_error_ios_signing_key_is_locked